# Generate a row with empty cells and a filled drop down list

Tags: javascript, html

I need to generate in JavaScript a new row on a table with a  (dropdown list) who is already filled and empty other cells and I want the function to work no matter which cells is the DropDown list in the row.

Here's my function :

```
function AddRows(tableid){
    var table = document.getElementById(tableid);
  var tbody = table.tBodies[0];
  var rowCount = tbody.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
  var lastRow = tbody.rows[rowCount-1];
  var clonedRow = lastRow.cloneNode(true);
       var editContent = !row.isContentEditable;
        row.contentEditable = editContent;
    row.setAttribute('onkeyup', "Disabled();");
    row.setAttribute('onclick', "SetSelectedRow(this)");
    row.setAttribute('id', 'Combo_row'+(row.rowIndex - 1)); //Set the id of the row
    row.setAttribute('class', 'default');

  for(i=0; i< clonedRow.cells.length;i++){
  var clonedcell = clonedRow.cells[i];
    if(!clonedcell.children[0]){
        clonedcell.innerText= "";
    }
  }
  tbody.appendChild(clonedRow);

}
```

And here's what i get : [image]

The problem is that when i add a row it keep what i added on the input and i only want to keep whats in the dropdown list the other cell should be empty cause i want the user to insert other information

Comment: That's one of the problems of cloning, is that content is cloned as well. You have 3 options: 1. Use another method to add rows (there's more than one way to skin a cat), 2. Clear the fields before appending clone to DOM. 3. Have an invisible row or a `<template>` to copy from.

Comment: Do you have an idea of how to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution ! If someone need here's my working function :

```
/* function to add row with a select */
// lPos : list of cells position in the row to reset
function addSelect(SelectTableId, lPos) {
    var Table = document.getElementById(SelectTableId);                 // Get the table id
    var R = document.querySelectorAll('tbody .AddRowClass')[0];         // Get the row className
    var C = R.cloneNode(true);                                          // Clone the row
    for (let i = 0; i< lPos.length; i++){                               // Clear selected cells of the row
        C.children[lPos[i]].textContent = ""
    }
Table.appendChild(C);                                                   // Display the new row with filled dropdown list and empty cells

}
```